# Can CSS UNSET be applied to an element for a specific form only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Someone in our team has defined the hell out of the Legend element.  I need the native functionality of legend in fieldset for a specific HTML page, without damaging the current wacky re-definition of that element's initial state.

Is it possible to unset all the former CSS properties for this element and and apply my own on a specific HTML page only?

TIA

Comment: possible, but not simple or easy to do in a short bit of code.

Comment: Are you thinking of applying the long list of resets?

Comment: basically. if the team used a prefix on the rules, like an #id that you can change, it makes it a lot cleaner because you can change the id of the fieldset and not have to clobber each rule or get heavy-handed on a reset.

Comment: What if I add an id to my legends?  Can I isolate them all and override the present definitions?

Comment: adding an id will help create new more powerful rules, but if the old ones use something broad like `form fieldset { ...`, then you're still going to have to "reset" each offending rule